# After running the cygnus docker, it exists immediately (no errors though)

Tags: docker, fiware-cygnus

After having build the cygnus docker according to: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/tree/master/docker (source code from: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus.git ), without changing the configuration, the container runs as it should. However, it exists immediately after running (no errors though).

- What is the recommended way to keep the container running when using docker-compose? For now, adding "stdin_open: true" to the yml-file does the trick.

The reason for posting is that the documentation does not seem to address this issue (*cf.* http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.org/en/develop/index.html).

Thanks!

Comment: Please, run `docker ps -a` to get the `container_id` of the exited container, and after that check `docker logs <container_id>`. Can you post what did you get after that?

Comment: There are no logs (doing as you asked) for the exited container. In fact, when I keep it running with "stdin_open: true" there are no logs either. Just to be sure, I checked other containers (orion, mongo), and they do give output.

Comment: are you running docker-compose detached? i.e. `docker compose up -d`? Or in the foreground?

Comment: I ran it both in the foreground and in the background. No logging in either case. Nor on the screen (pertaining to cygnus that is) when running it in the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, Instead of `master`, use the containers built with the code found in [this commit](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/commit/fc3cc26bf2a01c317cb7f15c8de5649b68f7642f). There is a pending [Pull Request](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/pull/695) to fix this needed java version bump.